# jqGrid inside a bootstrap tab won't show

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid JS 5.3.0 with styleUI set to Bootstrap. The grid displays fine without bootstrap tabs, but with this html (below copied from getbootstrap.com with mygrid "embedded") the content area is blank with no grid.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">

<div><table id="mygrid"></table><div id="mygrid_pager"></div></div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

How can I make it work inside a "tab-pane"? TIA. 
(can't include javascript code of creating "mygrid" right now)

Comment: you need to add the class `in` for the tab making `<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">` and you also need to move the `<table id="mygrid"></table>` inside that div. `<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab"> <table id="mygrid"></table></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code from

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
<div><table id="mygrid"></table>
```

to

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab"> <table id="mygrid"></table></div>
```

adding the `in` class to your #home will show it on load (judging from `<a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>` you want it to show on load)
and moving `<table id="mygrid"></table>` into `div#home` will show your grid inside the tab.

Comment: Great! it works.. partially. With autowidth: true, the grid still shrinks to left side of screen with about 1/3 width of full viewport. no shrinkToFit is set. What am I missing?

Comment: Well you need to ask another question about it. If this has answered your question please accept it.