# jqgrid autowidth set to true doesn't expand the grid to full width inside a bootstrap tab

Tags: jqgrid

I'm continuing this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033346/jqgrid-inside-a-bootstrap-tab-wont-show). Basically, I'm using jqGrid JS 5.3.0 with styleUI set to Bootstrap. The grid is inside a ".tab-pane" of a bootstrap tabs(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/). The problem is that the grid shrinks to the left side of the tab pane on about 1/3 of full tab/screen width. I haven't set shrinkToFit but autowidth:true. Is there a cure for this? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good to know which Bootstrap is used 3 or 4, since Guriddo jqGrid support both with different style sheets.

The autowidth option work on element which width is known. The tab initially has a width = 0 which causes maybe this problem.

You can try to enclose the jqGrid code within setTimeout function with enough delay (since of the Bootstrap effects when opening the tab).

If the problem is not solved, please post your code ( jsfiddle.net or other place) to revise it and recommend a solution.

Comment: Works! Even better, I load the grid in tabs' 'shown.bs.tab' event handler, and the grid table works inside a div too!